# Find the equation of the tangent plane to the graph of the function given by $f (x, y) = x^2 − 2xy + 2y^2$ having slope 2 to +x and slope 4 to +y

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the tangent plane to the graph of the function given by $f (x, y) = x^2 − 2xy + 2y^2$ having slope 2 in the positive x-direction and slope 4 in the positive y-direction.

It seems easy but i'm having trouble finding where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the fact that 
$$f_x(x,y) = 2 $$
and
$$f_y(x,y) = 4$$

Find the normal and any point on the plane and plug it into your favourite plane equation.

Comment: So for $f_x(x,y)=2x−2y=2$. So the normal is the negative reciprocal of 2. 

Hence $2x−2y=−1/2$ --> (A) 

by symmetry $f_x(x,y)=4y−2x=−1/4$   also --> call this (B)

B-A = 2y = -3/4, y=-3/8, 

subbing this onto A... 2x+3/4 = = -1/2, x = (-2-3)/2*(1/2) = 5/4

Comment: Oh wait i've gotten confused. Basically think the gradient of normal -1/4 or -1/2 is but where do i plug this into?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just this $z= f(a,b) + (x-a)(f_x(x,y)+(y-b)(f_b(y-b)$

i find a and b by solving 2x-2y=2 and 4y-2x = 4.

We gets you x=4 and y-3 and f(4,3) = 18

so z the tangent now is....
Z = 18 + (x-4,y-3)(2,4) = 2x=4y-2